# How do I refer to pointers in nested structs?

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, typedef

I'm fairly new to C pointers so I'm trying to play around with them to figure out how they work, more in depth.
I've got the following data types, defined with `typedef`:

```
struct node
{
    int key;
    struct node * prev;
    struct node * next;
};

typedef struct node node_t;

struct list
{
    node_t * head;
    node_t * tail;
};

typedef struct list list_t;
```

My goal is to have a doubly linked list with a pointer to its head and its tail, maybe with `tail->next` pointing to the head; in order to have a circular list.
The problem is that whenever I try to refer to any of the node's pointers, I get a segmentation fault.
I coded a function like this:

```
list_t * create_new_list()
{
    list_t * new_list;
    new_list->head = malloc( sizeof(node_t) );
    new_list->tail = malloc( sizeof(node_t) );

    // I've also tried
    // list * new_list = malloc( sizeof(list_t) );
    // but it doesn't work */


    /* init the head node */
    new_list->head->prev = NULL;
    new_list->head->next = NULL;
    new_list->head->key = 0;

    /* init the tail node */
    new_list->tail->prev = NULL;
    new_list->tail->next = NULL;
    new_list->tail->key = 0;

    return new_list;
}
```

When I call `create_new_list()` from my `main()` function I get:
"Segmentation Fault. Core dump created".

```
int main()
{
    list_t * my_list = create_new_list();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you check the core dump then?

Comment: It makes a lot of difference whether it is circular or not. Please clarify what you want.

Comment: *Where* have you tried your `malloc`? You first need to `malloc` your new_list, then your head and tail.  You can't dereference a list that's not there.

Comment: As a side note, `head` and `tail` nodes of your empty list are not connected. Is this intentional? I think you want want `create_new_list` to make both `head` and `tail` null, and then when you actually add 1st element to the list, then they will both point to this one element (it is, after all, tail and head). Or if you want sentinel tail and head elements (so empty list has 2 "fake" elements, unusual but might make sense sometimes), then their `next`/`prev/` should be initialized accordingly.

Comment: @RoiHatam honestly I've never done that before, honestly. I should look at how to do that. I'm not asking here because I don't want to insert a question into another question. Thank you anyhow :)

Comment: @4386427 How is that different? Don't I need just to assign the value of the head pointer to `tail->next`?
And `head->prev` to the tail of course...

Comment: @hyde I wanted to set the pointers correctly as soon as I insert the first node :)

Comment: There are no nested `struct`s shown. A pointer is not the object it points to!

Comment: @Olaf you're actually right. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you never allocate any memory for the new list. Consequently

```
´new_list->head = ... `
```

will crash.

Try:

```
list_t * create_new_list()
{
    list_t * new_list = malloc(sizeof *new_list);  // Allocate a new list
    if (!new_list) exit(1);                        // Bail out if it failed
    new_list->head = NULL;                         // Initialize pointers
    new_list->tail = NULL;                         // Initialize pointers
    return new_list;                               // Return the new list
}
```

Don't allocate any nodes in the `create`function. Do that in an `insert` function.

Something like:

```
void insert(list_t *list, int key)
{
    node_t* new_node = malloc( sizeof *new_node );
    if (!new_node) exit(1);                        
    new_node->key = key;

    //... add the code to insert the node into the list
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked! The Chris Tuner's solution is also working though. I marked this because it was the first one

Comment: @brainplot my answer fixes the immediate problem covered by your question, but doesn't cover the other problems with your code

Comment: @ChrisTurner what do you mean? My code shows nothing special or particularly wrong I think, probabily apart from trying to initialize the nodes within the same function :/

Comment: @ChrisTurner - yes, your answer is correct as well. I'm sure OP gave you and upvote - just as I did.

Comment: @4386427 I actually did! Also, I think that passing the struct's name (node_t) as the sizeof argument looks a little bit neater (and more readable as well) rather than passing the portion pointed by new_node. You're answer is yet more complete though. That's it

Comment: @brainplot sorry, I did just mean the "trying to initialize the nodes" bit

Comment: @ChrisTurner yeah, I figured. Thank you. No worries :)

Answer (score 3):

```
list_t * new_list;
new_list->head = malloc( sizeof(node_t) );
```

This won't work as `new_list` doesn't have a value! You need to allocate memory for it as well. Try doing this

```
list_t * new_list = malloc(sizeof(list_t));
```